# Bind to list ASP.NET MVC dynamic jQuery index

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a set of list elements, that I create dynamically. Each of these list elements, contains an input text, whose value I want to pass to the controller.

## HTML

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
<button id="add">Add</button>

<script>
    var counter = 1;

    $('#add').click(function () {
        var text = '<input type="text" name="(what should I put here?)"></input>';
        var li = '<li>' + text + '</li>';

        $(li).appendTo('#list');
        counter++;
        return false;
    });
</script>
```

## View Model

```
public IEnumerable<string> list {get; set;}
...
```

How can I bind those values to my ViewModel implicitly? I have tried to use the `counter` variable to assign a name to each created element (like `list[counter]`), but on the controller side the `list` variable on my ViewModel still comes empty.

Comment: I'm really not a fan of creating html like this, IMHO it's poor practice and creates artifical coupling between layers/languages.  You should also include your controller methods signatures.

Comment: Is your action method look like `MyAction(string[] mylist)`?

Comment: @ErikPhilips I will update the post as soon as I can (probably tommorow). I am also not a fan of this kind of code, but if you have a better suggestion, please, point me to it :)

Comment: @SamFarajpourGhamari No, my action method receives a ViewModel. I will update the post soon with the controller signature.

Comment: @ManuelReis actually this may be my mistake, are you trying to allow a user to send multiple dynamic strings to a controller?

Comment: Because your posting back to a collection of value types, it need only be `name="list"`. Indexers are only necessary for complex objects, but if they are provided they must start at zero and be consecutive (your attempt at `list[counter]` would fail because you initialize `counter=1`)

Comment: @ErikPhilips That is exactly what I want to do! :) Try to imagine a "to-do" list; that's the kind of functionality I am aiming for.

Comment: @StephenMuecke This worked for me (it will even help me if I delete one of the strings at runtime). If you would write an answer saying that, I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your collection is for value type (`string`) only, then you can simply use

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    var text = '<input type="text" name="list"></input>';
    ....
});
```

It is only necessary to include indexers when the property is a member of a complex object.

If you do include the indexer, it must start at zero and be consecutive (unless you also include a special hidden input for to identify the indexer). Your attempt at using `list[counter]` failed because the value of `counter` is initialized to `1` (it would have worked had you initialized it to `var counter = 0;`)

Answer (score 3):

First I would base your counter on the amount of li's within your un-ordered list with:

```
$('#list > li').size()
```

Then in order to keep the model binder happy pre-fix your property with list:

```
'<input type="text" name="list[' + counter + ']"></input>'
```

The full code then becomes:

```
$('#add').click(function () {
    var counter = $('#list > li').size();
    var text = '<input type="text" name="list[' + counter + ']"></input>';
    var li = '<li>' + text + '</li>';

    $(li).appendTo('#list');
    return false;
});
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/agmst4eu/1/)**

Please note, you will have to change your view model property to an `IList` or `List` for indexing to work too:

```
public IList <string> list {get; set;}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer! While your answer is correct (and provides a smarter way on how to use the counter), Stephen Muecke's comment on the question is simpler and also works. I had no need to use a counter, and did not have to change the type of `list`on my ViewModel.

Comment: @ManuelReis Sorry from your code I had made the assumption it was a complex type with the `....` in the view model and that you had omitted the non-relevant code.

Comment: That's probably my fault, I never know how much code is "too much code" when asking a question. Thanks again for your help

Comment: @ManuelReis No problem, question was a good one and the code supplied was easy to re-create. You got the answer you needed. :)